# How to Drop X in Column names after Merge

Tags: r

I've merged two data frames by common row names, and the merge worked fine, but I am getting an x before each column name.

How can I remove the X from each column header?

```
z<- merge(p, y, by='ID')
head(z)

   ID         x     y   V1   X198101 X198102 X198103 X198104 X198105 X198106 
1 410320 -122.5417 37.75 NA  119.45   33.15  104.23    5.61    4.85       0       
2 410321 -122.5000 37.75 NA  129.49   37.76  114.94    5.28    5.24       0       
3 410322 -122.4583 37.75 NA  163.68   42.80  131.22    7.25    6.94       0       
4 410323 -122.4167 37.75 NA  141.14   32.26  110.45    7.77    4.62       0       
5 410324 -122.3750 37.75 NA  130.87   25.87  102.15    8.38    4.13       0       
6 410325 -122.3333 37.75 NA  129.03   25.21  102.37    9.42    4.35       0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to have column names not start with numbers.  By default, the `make.names` or `make.unique` adds the `X` prefix when it starts with numbers.  To remove it, one option is `sub`

```
names(z) <- sub("^X", "", names(z))
z
#      ID         x     y V1 198101 198102 198103 198104 198105 198106
#1 410320 -122.5417 37.75 NA 119.45  33.15 104.23   5.61   4.85      0
#2 410321 -122.5000 37.75 NA 129.49  37.76 114.94   5.28   5.24      0
#3 410322 -122.4583 37.75 NA 163.68  42.80 131.22   7.25   6.94      0
#4 410323 -122.4167 37.75 NA 141.14  32.26 110.45   7.77   4.62      0
#5 410324 -122.3750 37.75 NA 130.87  25.87 102.15   8.38   4.13      0
#6 410325 -122.3333 37.75 NA 129.03  25.21 102.37   9.42   4.35      0
```

If we apply `make.names`

```
make.names(names(z))
#[1] "ID"      "x"       "y"       "V1"      "X198101" "X198102" 
#[7] "X198103" "X198104" "X198105" "X198106"
```

The 'X' prefix is returned.  So, in general, it is safe to have column names with 'character' prefix instead of just numbers.  Also, if we wanted to extract say '198101' column, we need a backtick

```
z$198104
#Error: unexpected numeric constant in "z$198104"
z$`198104`
#[1] 5.61 5.28 7.25 7.77 8.38 9.42
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's it. The column names are dates (year then month), so they need to be numbers. Thanks for your quick response and explanation!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't actually caused by merge, it must be something earlier in your code. If it happens when you read in the data, try the `check.names=FALSE` option.

```
a <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6)
b <- data.frame(a=1:3, c=7:9)
names(b)[2] <- 2485
merge(a,b)
##   a b 2485
## 1 1 4    7
## 2 2 5    8
## 3 3 6    9
```

Comment: it didn't happen when I read in the data, but instead right after I merged.... but the check.names=FALSE option is good to keep in mind for the future. Thanks!